# Is this network of resistors in series and parallel, the way I intended?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series, breadboard

https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/gu5zh6pdvj8q/parallel-and-series-question-circuit/

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKLpWW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do these circuit schematics accurately represent these other 2 circuit schematics, which I made using Tinkercad?

[image]

If so, is the resistor network for C2 built to match the equation

1/(1/(330 + 330 + 330 + 220) + 1/(330 + 330 + 330 + 100))

Which represents one serial circuit with a combined value of 1110 ohms, and another of a combined value of 1090 ohms, both in parallel, which should give a combined ohm value at the output of the circuit of 570 ohms?

If yes, how come my multimeter reads 500 ohms at the beginning and the end of these resistor networks?

EDIT:

Solved, the 400/500 ohms is because of the tolerance.

Comment: You have one long series chain starting at A30 and ending at C29.

Comment: @Majenko How come? The resistor at A30 is not connected to the network starting from c29? And ar ethen added in parallel at 13?

Comment: `A30-|===|-A26-B26-|===|-B22-A22-|===|-A18-B18-|===|-B13-D13-|===|-D17-E17-|===|-E21-D21-|===|-D25-C25-|===|-C29`

Comment: 560 ohm and 10 ohm are common values so why all the drama?

Comment: @Majenko Suposse there was an electrical component like a motor input at 13e, would it still be so?

Comment: Until you have something connecting A30 and C29 (like you have done for the column 13) you won't have anything in parallel.

Comment: @jsotola Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You yet have to connect Line 29 with Line 30.
Then your curcuit represents your formula.

Comment: Thank you for you answer,

Could I possibly ask you to draw the schematics for it aswell, so I can understand how the schematics relate to real life better?

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump, much better if you draw the schematics yourself, then you'll really understand properly. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use.

Comment: @TonyM Well I gave it a go at that, and made my own diagrams.

I have added them to the edited question.

Perhaps you could take a look at it?

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump, thanks for putting the work in. It needs to be visible in your question rather than as a link. Readers need to see it in front of them and links can break anyway. Please can you make that edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Resistor value**

What is the resistor value 570 ohm for? Does it really matter if it is that precise? If 550 ohm would suffice, just add a 330 and 220 ohm resistor to get 550 ohm.

Note that each resistor has an accuracy so probably with two 5% precision resistors you get away with 550 ohms.

**Breadboard**

To put this on a breadboard, place one resistor from e.g. a30 to a26, and than on the same vertical line, starting at e.g. b26 to b22 the second resistor. Now you have the resistor in **series**.

To put two resistor in **parallel**, place two resistors with both ends on the same vertical lines, e.g. one from a30 to a26 and the second from b30 to b26.

Comment: Right, Tinkercad wouldn't allow me to change the size of the resistor, but in reality the last 220 and 110 ohm resistors are in parallel, with both sites sharing nodes. 

Also, it was not only because of me needing a 570 ohm resistor value, I also wanted to challenge myself and learn more about resistor networks.

Edit: Oh wait, the last resistors are only connected with one end. I will try to change that.

Comment: Remember that all points from a30 to e30 are connected,  same as a29 to e29 are connected etc.

Comment: Also you can create the two series subcircuits on each end (so one below the split line between e an f, and the other above), and than connect the most left ends together and most right ends (to make both series into a parallel configuration).

Comment: Well, that would be a possibility, but the schematics I made is not for the whole circuit, only the part with resistors. In real life the other part is filled with a potentiometer and a LED 8x8 matrix.

But thanks for the suggestion anyways, it has given me a new tool in the future :)

Comment: I also had troubles using a breadboard the first time, and also tried to mimic a resistor I didn't have as good as possible... It's both good learning experiences. If you get more into it, try later when you feel comfortable using a breadboard to move away from TinkerCad (not that it's not good), but use more Circuit-like editors (e.g. CircuitMaker, KiCad etc), they have some learning curve but greatly increase understanding of other circuits to if you start using them.

Comment: Yeah, I usually use CircuitMaker for making the circuits in the first place.

I just couldn't figure out how to translate the other way around. 

But I have tried to make some diagrams, perhaps I could ask you to take a look at them?

Comment: Ok you can … but I'm also just a hobbyist... By putting specific questions on this site you get the best answers as multiple people look at them.

Comment: It seems 400 ohm is strange (I didn't check all color codes of the resistors). However, you should measure each series (disconnect the other), to rule out which string is ok, than check each resistor separately (while breaking the rest of the circuit).

Comment: You can do a lot with this tool http://tinyurl.com/y37y79to